# Create GUID menu item missing in Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, create-guid

I do not see "Create GUID" option under the menu item Tools -> .  I am using Visual Studio 2005 .

Do I have to install anything for that .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely missing because the profile you chose does not include that particular option.  Try the following

1. Tools -> Import and Export Settings
2. Select "Reset all Settings" and hit Next
3. Select "No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings" and hit Next
4. Select "General Development Settings" and hit Finish

Now the "Create GUID" menu item should be present in the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Search your machine for "guidgen".